# Show that $ \lim\limits_{y\to \infty} \mathbb P(Y(y)\le \mathbb E(Y(y)))=1-\exp(-1) $

Tags: probability, limits, expectation, independence

How does one prove this?

Let $\{X_r: r\ge1\}$ be independent and identically distributed with distribution function $F$ satisfying $F(y)<1$ for all $y$, and let $Y(y)=\min\{k:X_k>y\}$. Show that

$$ \lim_{y\to \infty} \mathbb P(Y(y)\le \mathbb E(Y(y)))=1-\exp(-1) $$

Comment: $F$ is the CDF or the PDF of the $X_r$'s ? (Well I guess that the restriction $F(y) < 1$ for the CDF would be quite useless...)

Comment: How can we know what "a more concise and robust solution" could be if you do not give us "the solution for Ch 4.2 #4" and, even more importantly, do not indicate why it "is confusing (you) more than helping"?

Comment: @Did , I have revised the question. Does this address the issue?

Comment: Not really, obviously one needs to have the *One thousand exercises* book to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Did, how is that?

Comment: Worse than before, you suppressed a paragraph and now we simply have a question with zero context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A start:

\begin{align}
\Pr(Y(y) = k) &= \Pr(X_1 \leq y, ..., X_{k-1} \leq y, X_k >y) = p(y)^{k-1}(1-p(y))\\
\mathrm{E}(Y(y)) &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k p^{k-1}(1-p(y)) = (1-p(y)) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}p(y)} \frac{1}{1-p(y)} = (1-p(y)) \frac{1}{(1-p(y))^2}\\ &= \frac{1}{1-p(y)}\\
\Pr(Y(y) \leq \mathrm{E}(Y(y))&= \Pr\left(Y(y) \leq \frac{1}{1-p(y)}\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor 1/(1-p(y)) \rfloor} p(y)^{k-1}(1-p(y))\\
&= (1-p(y)) \frac{1-p(y)^{\lfloor 1/(1-p(y)) \rfloor+1}}{1-p(y)}\\
&= 1-p(y)^{\lfloor 1/(1-p(y)) \rfloor+1}
\end{align}
I have used the notation
$$
p(y) = \Pr(X_1 \leq y).
$$